# Do fiends need to sleep?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, rests, sleep

The Monster Manual states that undead and constructs do not need to sleep.

**But it is unclear if fiends need to sleep. What should they do to make a long rest?**

There are fiendish abilities with "recharges after short or long rest" (such as animate chains of the [chain devil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chain-devil)), that's why they definitely should rest in some kind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes

Since there are no specific rules for fiends, they use the general [rule](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Resting).

> A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long, during which a character **sleeps for at least 6 hours** ...

Of course, if you don’t want fiends to sleep to rest in your world, then they don’t.

Comment: (And obviously, specific fiends could have specific traits that supersede the general rule - but as the answer says, there's no general rule changing the need to sleep for fiends in general.)